# asp.net UpdatePanel Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

i have this templateField in GridView with problem that is unresponsive on pageload.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional"  >
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="obdobje" EventName="TextChanged"  />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButtonrefresh" EventName="Click"  />

        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Caption="Ure zaposlenih:"
                runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                AllowSorting="true"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                DataKeyNames="anPeriodID, acDepartmentID"
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                CssClass="display table table-striped table-bordered">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="3%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img name="img1" id="img1" alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" runat="server"  />
                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                <table class="table  table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <asp:Label ID="LabelExcel" runat="server" Text="error"></asp:Label>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel> 
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="anPeriodID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="anPeriodID" Visible="false" HtmlEncode="false"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="acDepartmentID" HeaderText="Poslovalnica" SortExpression="acDepartmentID" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-Width="47%"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="anYear" HeaderText="Leto" SortExpression="anYear" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="anMonth" HeaderText="Mesec" SortExpression="anMonth" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="anHours" HeaderText="Suma ur del." ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="anCount" HeaderText="Št. del." ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="anControl" HeaderText="* -/+15 h" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Potrjeno SM" ItemStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkClosed2" Checked='<%# Eval("anConfirmed1") %>' runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zaključeno" ItemStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkClosed" Checked='<%# Eval("anConfirmed2") %>' runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

LabelExcel is a generated HTML table.

java script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $("img[name='img1']").on({
            'click': function () {
                if ($(this).attr('src') === 'images/plus.png') {
                    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
                    $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

if i run this code:

```
protected void LinkButtonrefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePanel3.Update();
}
```

plus (+) and (-) in gridview are working just fine. 
if i try to do this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    CheckSession();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        obdobje.DataSource = GetActivePeriods(UserCompany);
        obdobje.DataTextField = "acPeriodID";
        obdobje.DataValueField = "acPeriodID";
        obdobje.DataBind();
        UpdatePanel3.Update();
    }
    Grid_Reload(0);
   }
```

nothing happens

tried with timer:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="true"  Interval="3000"   OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>        


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
    UpdatePanel3.Update();
    BootStrapAlert(LabelInfo, "test", BootstrapAlertType.Information);
}
```

text "test" is refreshed.. but UpdatePanel3 is not.. if i click on a button it's ok.

Comment: Please mention everithing you tried.

Comment: it seems that its working now. i moved JS (function pageLoad) fro master to content page.